# printing ansi colors/escape codes with a2ps

Tags: colors, escape-characters, a2ps

Is it possible for [a2ps](https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) to interpret the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) ?

```
$ echo -e "\033[31mHello\e[0m World" | ./bin/a2ps -o output.ps
```

if not, do you know another tool that would do this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## aha - Ansi HTML Adapter

Converts ANSI escape sequences of a unix terminal to HTML code.

[aha Git repo](https://github.com/theZiz/aha)

Then you just need a tool to make HTML to PS like [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html).